# How do I deploy Sinatra + mustache onto Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, mustache

I have a really basic Sinatra site working locally. I am using the "rackup" thing, where you define a `config.ru` like this:

```
require './web'

use Rack::ShowExceptions

run App.new
```

And then in the terminal you can run 'rackup' and a web server is fired up and all is well.

However, when I deploy this to heroku I don't get any error messages, but, when I visit the site, it says the standard "Sinatra does not know this ditty" error.

Here is a snippet of my `web.rb` in case it helps:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'maruku'
require 'mustache/sinatra'
require 'nokogiri'

class App < Sinatra::Base
    register Mustache::Sinatra
    require './views/layout'

    set :mustache, {
        :views     => './views/',
        :templates => './templates/'
    }

    get '/' do
       "FUUUUUUUUUUUUU"
    end
```

- Edit

Looking at the heroku logs, it *appears* like sinatra starts and then stops; it doesn't keep running. Then when someone makes a request obviously the server returns a 404

```
2012-01-20T12:39:23+00:00 app[web.1]: == Sinatra/1.1.0 has taken the stage on 16662 for development with backup from Thin
2012-01-20T12:39:23+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.7 codename No Hup)
2012-01-20T12:39:23+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2012-01-20T12:39:23+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:16662, CTRL+C to stop
2012-01-20T12:39:23+00:00 app[web.1]: == Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
2012-01-20T12:39:23+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-01-20T12:39:23+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2012-01-20T12:39:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2012-01-20T12:39:24+00:00 heroku[router]: GET young-river-2245.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=48ms status=404 bytes=409
```

Comment: Are you getting anything from running `heroku logs` in the project's directory?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any obvious errors, mentions of sinatra taking the stage and such, nothing else interesting.

Comment: Is your request there? With a 404?

Comment: Yeah: 2012-01-19T23:44:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 93.97.193.95 - - [19/Jan/2012 23:44:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 409 0.0020

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you inherit from `Sinatra::Base` you must `require 'sinatra/base'` rather than `require 'sinatra'` at the top of your `web.rb` file.

I just ran a simple test using your snippets and was able to replicate and then fix the error by doing this.